# why isn't this div sitting at bottom for iphone?

Tags: iphone, css

it works fine on desktop & android... but not on mobile?

css:

```
display:block;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
width:94%;
padding:15px 3% 0px 3%;
height:185px;
z-index:10;
background-color:#ffffff;
border-top: 1px solid #c9cfdd;
margin:0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
transition-duration: .25s;
```

the div isn't in a wrapper or anything as it sits over the top of the content. In iPhone it sits about 50px off the bottom?

EDIT:

position: fixed works, but why not position:absolute? I need position:absolute to work for other reasons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by adding this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```